# Vertical column pushed down other grid elements // Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm a trying to understand how i can make the grid correct for my needs, but i broken my mind. Sorry for my english - just look at the screenshots.

[>What I'm getting!<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgQmL.png)

[>What I need!<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tt0T.png)

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is simple version of my grid - [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kindsage/7omn0hpf/)

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but I'm assuming you want to ensure that all columns in a row stay the same height. If so, check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: @sean  I found this solution, but now i need to add block Sidebar under LOGO div:    https://jsfiddle.net/kindsage/e7L6Lc1n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple, all what you need is to ensure that logo wrapper will be big enough. You can also use div with `.clearfix` class or enforce height via css. Here is working example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyGKEL

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #logo img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        #sidebar {
            border: 1px solid black;
            clear: both;
            float: left;
        }

        #logo {
            padding: 10px 0
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" id="logo">

                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x400" width="100%" />
            </div>  

            <div class="col-md-2 bullet">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut leo a
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-2 bullet">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut leo a
            </div>

             <div class="col-md-2 bullet">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut leo a
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4" id="phone">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut leo a
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10" id="nav">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>


            <div class="col-md-9">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut leo aLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut 
       </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2" id="sidebar">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse at laoreet nisl, vel consequat purus. Aenean ligula arcu, viverra ut leo a
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try! What do you think about this? https://jsfiddle.net/kindsage/e7L6Lc1n/ How i can add Sidebar under LOGO div?

Comment: I updated code so you can check out how it is working with fixed height and sidebar under logo wrapper.

Comment: I see. This is main problem - logo has unfixed heigh

Comment: Then you can try to use float and clear css prop - check out  my answer again

Comment: Woof! Thank you! I make some changes in your code and i think this is what i got! - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyGKEL

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer help you please mark it as accepted. Feel free to ask if you will have any other problems :)